# Python: How to subtract timestamps from a column and create a new TimeElapsed column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a couple of columns in my `dataframe` that looks like this:

```
ContextID Time_ms
    1   09:12:48.502
    1   09:12:48.603
    1   09:12:48.934
    2   09:15:36.434
    2   09:15:36.654
    3   09:17:55.940
    3   09:17:56.160
    3   09:17:57.267
```

What I would like to do is to create a new column named `TimeElapsed` (preferably containing values in milliseconds) for each `ContextID` and it must contain values as follows:

```
ContextID   Time_ms Time_Elapsed
1   09:12:48.502    0
1   09:12:48.603    09:12:48.603 - 09:12:48.502
1   09:12:48.934    09:12:48.934 - 09:12:48:502 
2   09:15:36.434    0
2   09:15:36.654    09:15:36.654 - 09:15:36.434
3   09:17:55.940    0
3   09:17:56.160     09:17:55.940 -09:17:55.940
3   09:17:57.267    09:17:57.267 - 09:17:55.940
```

The first value of the `Time_ms` of every `ContextID` must be 0secs and then the second value of `Time_ms` must be subtracted from the first `Time_ms` and so on and the difference must fill the `Time_Elapsed` column.

I would like to know how can this be implemented using Pandas in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the result of `groupby` + `transform`:

```
#df['Time_ms'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time_ms)
df['Time_Elapsed'] = df.Time_ms - df.groupby('ContextID').Time_ms.transform('first')

   ContextID         Time_ms    Time_Elapsed
0          1 09:12:48.502000        00:00:00
1          1 09:12:48.603000 00:00:00.101000
2          1 09:12:48.934000 00:00:00.432000
3          2 09:15:36.434000        00:00:00
4          2 09:15:36.654000 00:00:00.220000
5          3 09:17:55.940000        00:00:00
6          3 09:17:56.160000 00:00:00.220000
7          3 09:17:57.267000 00:00:01.327000
```

---

Transform is used to broadcast the groupby result back to the shape of the original `DataFrame`. In this case we want the first value so we can perform a single subtraction:

```
df.groupby('ContextID').Time_ms.transform('first')

#0   09:12:48.502000
#1   09:12:48.502000
#2   09:12:48.502000
#3   09:15:36.434000
#4   09:15:36.434000
#5   09:17:55.940000
#6   09:17:55.940000
#7   09:17:55.940000
#Name: Time_ms, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Hey @ALollz, I first used `df['Time_ms'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time_ms)` then ran the next line of code and it gives me output as follows: `0 days 00:00:00.101000000`. I would like to know 2 things: 1. How can I get rid of the 0 days?  2. Is there a way that the output just looks like either 0.1010 sec or 1010ms instead of 00:00:00.101000000?

Comment: @Bibliophile20: `(df['Time_Elapsed'] = df.Time_ms - df.groupby('ContextID').Time_ms.transform('first')).dt.total_seconds`?

Comment: @Graipher: It throws the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'TimedeltaIndex' and 'method'`

Comment: @Bibliophile20: Sorry, `(df['Time_Elapsed'] = df.Time_ms - df.groupby('ContextID').Time_ms.transform('first')).dt.total_seconds()`.

Comment: @Graipher: It worked perfectly. I have a question though: Is it necessary to do `df['Time_ms'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time_ms)` before running your code? I tried running without it, it threw the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @Bibliophile20: Yes, you first have to convert it to datetime objects.

Comment: @Graipher I had one more question. After the column is converted to datetime objects, is there a way to obtain the old column version back?